# Flashing when switching between view controllers

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics, uiviewcontroller, core-graphics

I got 2 view controllers and I'm having trouble to switch between them. For example:

I displayed view controller A. The user taps a button and I have to display view controller B. I need to close A and open B. The problem is that when I close A and open B, the screen flashes for a second instead of just showing B. I believe I have to freeze graphics or something like that. Since I might have to switch back from B to A or even from B to C or A to C or C to B, opening B from A is not an option.

Does anyone know any kind of solution for that?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[self presentViewController:targetvc animated:NO completion:nil]
```

Comment: I did. Please read my question again. I want to dismiss a VC and open another one without the user seeing the main VC between the transition.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what you are trying to achieve??

Comment: There's no code snippet. I'm using the very same code to open the VCs you posted. But I need to open a new view controller before closing the old one. Hence, a code snippet would mean my whole view controller code.